# Situar los elementos con la misma clase en columnas ordenadas

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer un masonry layout y la logica es la siguiente
tengo un arreglo de elementos [elem1,elem2,elem3,elem4] y deseo distribuirlos en 3 columnas, pero deben aparecer en este orden:

```
columna1 columna2 columna3
elem1    elem2     elem3
```

Por alguna razón el primer elemento no se agrega, no entiendo porque

este es mi código javascript:

no comprendo porque no se agregan todos los elementos, incluso probé con un arreglo de números para ver la lógica y los números se agregaban correctamente

```
let articles = document.getElementsByClassName("new-article")

let columns = [document.createElement("div"),
               document.createElement("div"),
               document.createElement("div")]

let longElements = articles.length-1
let elementsCounter = 0

for(let i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("container-articles").appendChild(columns[i])
}


for(let i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
    columns[i].classList.add("col-xl-4")
}

for(let i=0; i<=columns.length; i++){
  if(i===columns.length){
      i=0;
  }
  if(longElements<0){
      break
  }
  columns[i].appendChild(articles[elementsCounter])
  longElements--
  elementsCounter++
}
```

Aquí pruebo el algoritmo con números antes de usar el DOM

```
let elementos = [12,12,3,41,2]
let columnas = [[],[],[]]
let longElementos = elementos.length-1 //4

    for(let i=0; i<=columnas.length; i++){ //i=0,1,2,3
       if(i===columnas.length){  // i=0,1,2,3
         i=0
       }
       if(longElementos<0){  // longElementos  2,41,3,12,12
         break
       }
       columnas[i].push(elementos[longElementos]) //3,2,1,0
       longElementos--
    }
```

La salida es esta, que es justo la que espero:

```
 arr1--->   0: [2, 12]
 arr2--->   1: [41, 12]
 arr3--->   2: [3]
```

**Actualizacion:**

Aqui esta el HTML que estoy usando

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>



<article class="new-article">
 <img src="http:lorempixel.com/500/500">
 <h1>Noticia 1</h1>
</article>

<article class="new-article">
 <img src="http:lorempixel.com/500/500">
 <h1>Noticia 2</h1>
</article>


<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row" id="container-articles">
   </div>
</div>
<script src="masonry.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está en que estás iterando a través del array `articles` a la vez que vas moviendo los elementos que están dentro del mismo dentro del HTML.

Por definición, la función `getElementsByClassName` te devuelve un [**`HTMLCollection`**](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#old-style-collections) que es un objeto que representa una lista de nodos. Esta lista está ordenada (a no ser de que se le indique lo contrario) respetando el orden del árbol del HTML. Además, **esta lista está viva**, lo que quiere decir que **cualquier cambio que se produzca en ella, va a alterar la lista**.

En tu caso, pongámonos en el último for (en el que asignas los artículos a las distintas columnas) lo que está pasando es lo siguiente:

- En la primera iteración el array `articles` está ordenado [Noticia 1, Noticia 2] y la variable es `i=0`. Accedes a la `columna[0]` y al `articles[0]` y la Noticia 1 pasa a estar dentro del `container-articles`. Todo va perfecto.
- Veamos que ocurre en la siguiente iteración del array. El array `articles` -recordemos que es una lista viva y que respeta el orden del HTML- esta vez contendrá los valores así [Noticia 2, Noticia 1] ya que ahora Noticia 1 está más abajo que Noticia 2 en el árbol del HTML. Sin embargo, `i=1` por lo que va a posicionar de nuevo Noticia 1 dentro de `container-articles` dejando fuera del mismo a la Noticia 2.

Para solucionarlo, he creado una variable `j=0` que reseteo en cada iteración del bucle y que usaré para obtener los artículos. Obtengo siempre el artículo que esté en la posición 0 ya que al estar ordenado el array `articles` según el orden que tiene el HTML y siendo que cada vez que posicionamos un elemento lo establecemos más abajo que los artículos dentro del orden del HTML, conforme vaya moviendo los distintos artículos el elemento siguiente que tengo que mover va a ser siempre el primero del array.

Además, hago una comprobación para ver si hay más columnas que artículos que en ese caso controlo el error que daría al intentar meter en una columna un hijo que no existe.

**Nota:** He eliminado tus variables `longElements` y `elementsCounter` ya que no las he visto necesarias.

Tu código corregido:

```js
let articles = document.getElementsByClassName("new-article")

let columns = [document.createElement("div"),
               document.createElement("div"),
               document.createElement("div")]

for(let i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("container-articles").appendChild(columns[i])
}

for(let i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
    columns[i].classList.add("col-xl-4")
}

let columnas = document.getElementsByClassName("col-xl-4")
for(let i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
  j=0;
  if(articles[i] != undefined){
     columnas[i].appendChild(articles[j])
  }  
}
```

```html
<article class="new-article">
 <img src="http:lorempixel.com/500/500">
 <h1>Noticia 1</h1>
</article>

<article class="new-article">
 <img src="http:lorempixel.com/500/500">
 <h1>Noticia 2</h1>
</article>

<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row" id="container-articles">
   </div>
</div>
```